# Build docker image using jenkins dynamic agents. DIND windows

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows, docker-in-docker

Im trying to build a windiws docker container on a windows host. I need a solution like DinD that would work on windows.

More Context, have been trying to migrate jenkins to use dynamic on Kubernetes. everything has worked on linux so far, had to use BuildKit which doesnt seem to have a windows alternative.

How could I use DinD using windows. Is it even possible to do so?

I have tried so far to mount the socket. Not sure if my config is working.